# Is it feasible to use WebRTC PeerConnection for video conferencing with more than two participants?

Tags: javascript, video-conferencing, webrtc

I've been playing with WebRTC and reading about the way it works, but I'm still quite ignorant of what's really going on under hood when it comes to peer connections. The way that the streams are routed, won't it choke if there's too many participants in a video conference without some sort of central server, if they all have to connect to one another?

Has anyone experimented with this? Anyone care to take a guess at the threshold for your average broadband connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will definitely choke whatever it is that you are doing.

You will need a central server, but that is up to you - WebRTC only deals with the media transport and communication part - you need to take of the signalling of it all on your own.
To that end, you can add a media server to handle multipoint conferences and have it do the orchestration of the conference.

Comment: There isn't any out of the box that I know of. There are companies working on it such as tokbox and tenhands - you can reach out to them. Also check out https://github.com/sdslabs/hackview for a hacked beginning of an MCU implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that's definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at webrtc.io
http://multiwebrtc.nodejitsu.com/#0

but like @Tsahi says it chokes .. chocked for me after 4 participants and cpu spiked to 100% lots of delays as well. When you are not doing 1 on 1

Comment: this URL not working for me. I am also looking for Multi user video chat

Comment: This is the official github repo where the code resides https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io it appears that the example site is not available anymore - Feel free to contact the devs for more info.